# How to read a certain string in HttWebRequest

Tags: html, vb.net, http, bots

I am trying to get the pricetag from multiple websites using HTTPWebRequest

Here is one thats more difficult [LINK](http://us.bape.com/collections/men/products/1d30-141-006) I am trying to get the pricetag from the combobox

Here is one that is more simple (i think), [LINK](http://www.footlocker.com/product/model:262605/sku:43392411/nike-kd-9-mens/kevin-durant/blue/white/)

How do I parse just the pricetag?

Comment: You're not using both VBA and VB.Net, so which one is it?

Comment: .VB files, visual basic i guess?

Comment: HTTPWebRequest is vb.net, can you update the tags?

Comment: donw, now can you answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer in VBA, it is easily ported to .Net.

```
Sub test()
    'Add a reference to MSXML 6.0
    Dim getreq      As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim html        As Object: Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim elements    As Object
    Dim element     As Object

    'Get the HTML from the server
    With getreq
        .Open "GET", "http://us.bape.com/collections/men/products/1d30-141-006"
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
        .send
        .waitForResponse 5

        'Create an in memory HTML document with the page's HTML
        html.body.innerhtml = .responseText
    End With

    'Print out the InnerText, use getelementbyid to find the element
    Debug.Print html.getelementbyid("product-select").innertext

    'If there are multiple options, find the element, then iterate the options
    'Set elements = html.getelementbyid("product-select").getElementsByTagName("option")

    'iterate the options
    'For Each element In elements
    '    Debug.Print element.innertext
    'Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The general approach is applicable in several situations, yes.

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question. I'd recommend closing this question (accept it as an answer if this helped) and ask a new question